# Is there a way to embed metadata into an Apostrophe CMS version 3 user type

Tags: mongodb, apostrophe-cms

I am looking into the Apostrophe CMS for a way to embed data into the mongoDB user documents so that I can keep more data about a given user beyond just their username, password, and role (admin, guest, contributor, etc).

Looking through the Apostrophe CMS version 3 documentation (https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/guide/users.html) there seems to be no information about how to interact with the database so that more data can be added to a user. As it stands there don't seem to be any methods available to interact with the database in this fasion.

An example might be:

```
user: {
    role: guest,
    group: eastUS,
    groupID: 1jfe25226,
    isActive: true,
    hasBeenContacted: true
}
```

If anyone has attempted to do this or successfully achieved this please let me know your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe users are just Apostrophe pieces. That means you can extend them with custom fields in a project-level `modules/@apostrophecms/user/index.js` file, just like you would add fields to any piece type. This gives you a way to add additional editable fields.

The [documentation on queries](https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/guide/database-queries.html#query-across-modules) also applies to users. However bear in mind that for security reasons only admins can query for users or update them.

To update a single custom property of the current user you might write the following inside an Apostrophe `apiRoute`, promise event handler, etc.:

```
await self.apos.doc.db.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $set: { group: 'xyz' } });
```

This goes directly to MongoDB to `$set` one property and bypasses permissions checks, so use with care.

Apostrophe's standard [REST APIs](https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/api/pieces.html) also work for users, but bear in mind that for security reasons only an admin user can fetch and edit users.

I can revise and add more clarification if you can be more specific about what you are trying to do and in what situation.